# Dependency injection to a gRPC service

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection, grpc

I have created a gRPC service using Protobuff in Visual Studio with .NET core and I want to test the service.

The service got a constructor:

```
public ConfigService(ILogger<ConfigService> logger)
{
    _logger = logger;
}
```

Like the ILogger which is somehow injected (and I have no idea how), I want to inject an additional parameter - an interface. This interface is supposed to be easily set during runtime since I want to set a certain class when running a real run and a mock class when testing. for example something like:

```
public ConfigService(ILogger<ConfigService> logger, IMyInterface instance)
{
    _logger = logger;
    _myDepndency = instance;
}
```

and that in a real run instance will be `new RealClass()` but when testing it'll be easy to pass `new MockClass()`.

The startup class is still the default:

```
 public class Startup
{
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddGrpc();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapGrpcService<ConfigService>();

            endpoints.MapGet("/", async context =>
            {
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Communication with gRPC endpoints must be made through a gRPC client. To learn how to create a client, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2086909");
            });
        });
    }
}
```

How can I inject to the 2nd parameter of the constructor of the service?

Comment: Create an implementation or mock of the interface and pass it to the subject under test

Comment: Show the test and where you are having issues

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the simplest form you can just add your dependency to the `IServiceCollection` in the `ConfigureServices` method;

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddGrpc();
    services.AddScoped<IMyInterface, MyClassImplementingInterface>();
}
```

This will register your dependency in the service collection and enable it to be injected automatically through constructor injection. In your test you will inject it yourself as a mock as you seem to be aware of.

See this link for reference: [Dependency injection in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: In the test you mean there I can simply create the service instance myself? new ConfigService(null, new MyMock());   ?

Comment: Yep, something like that. You could also have a look at a mocking framework (such as moq: https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) which will help you mock your dependencies.

Comment: I am noticing that the constructor for MyClassImplementingInterface keeps running every time the gRPC endpoint receives a request. Is there any way to make it so that MyClassImplementingInterface is instantiated only once and re-used? (for me this is opening an LMDB database each time... this should only happen once!)

I guess what I am asking is... how do I store global state and access it from gRPC service for expensive-to-instantiate class libraries?

Comment: edit: Nevermind. service.AddSingleton<IMyInterface, MyClassImplementingInterface>();
is doing the trick for my usecase.

Comment: @DaggeJ maybe a late question. After registering the dependency, how can I get it back at the grpc service? In the reference link, it show how we can get it at Main() function, serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMyDependency>(). But how can I get it in my grpc service class? Let say I have a gRPC class 
public class GreeterService: GreeterServiceBase{
public override Task<SayHelloResponse> SayHlelo(SayHelloRequest request, ServerCallContext context) {...}
}.
It seems that I cannot get the IServiceCollection from the context object.

Comment: @kzfid - Just inject it via constructor injection - create an interface for your implementation class, register it as shown above and create a constructor in the class where you want to use it accepting an instance of the interface type. The DI framework makes this work automatically. Normally you never get instances directly from the service provider.

Comment: @DaggeJ Never aware that it is done by the DI framework automatically by constructor injection. Thanks.